# Test User Pages - can we create them via API?

Tags: facebook, api, testing

We've developed a FB application that reads/analyzes Insights data from a user's pages.  We are having OAuth problems with user who administer large numbers of pages (> 25).

We are looking for a way to automate creation of test users with large numbers of pages, but it appears that you cannot create a page using the API :  [Mentionned in this discussion](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4574579/create-a-new-facebook-page-via-the-fb-api)

Is there any way to automatically create pages for TEST USERS?  This would be a big help for setting up test environments.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to create pages at all.

So **no**, you can't